# Why pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill() method doesn`t work?

Tags: python, pygame

We want to kill bird when it is at up or down but kill method doesn`t works.

We tested code and and understood that this is all pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill() method. Down there is Lorem Ipsum because we can`t publish the question. We are very sorry about this.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis consequat nulla, volutpat tristique nulla interdum eget. Donec sagittis dui et lacus pretium placerat. Ut ullamcorper auctor mi, vel tempus risus fringilla at. Pellentesque imperdiet lacus ipsum, blandit elementum dui commodo in. Nunc gravida non ligula quis mollis. Nulla ipsum sem, efficitur eu justo in, dapibus efficitur nisi. Nunc eu est consectetur, laoreet diam quis, ullamcorper sem. Maecenas sit amet vestibulum erat. Ut egestas sed purus vitae auctor. Vivamus a semper mi, id fringilla neque.

Duis feugiat sem ac metus malesuada elementum. Nullam convallis ac turpis sit amet dictum. Fusce semper felis orci, non lacinia justo consectetur sit amet. Vestibulum arcu massa, fermentum ut pulvinar a, sodales sed neque. Donec varius mi vel lacus vulputate, et rutrum lorem tincidunt. Sed molestie dignissim porta. Fusce sed lacus nec diam lobortis dignissim. Ut ut felis aliquet, tristique felis interdum, vestibulum nibh. Fusce ligula sem, porta sit amet tellus a, ornare imperdiet dui. Suspendisse pharetra nisl at nisi lacinia imperdiet. Fusce ac dui justo. Nam id consequat justo, non imperdiet sapien. Morbi vulputate sem nec suscipit suscipit.

Aenean placerat consectetur ex sit amet gravida. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam dictum a urna eget lacinia. Pellentesque sed quam nec eros pellentesque finibus. Mauris lacus quam, lacinia eu mi in, elementum tincidunt ante. Quisque efficitur id mi sit amet rutrum. Phasellus luctus velit ac urna laoreet, id convallis diam placerat. Vestibulum tincidunt magna ut dolor mollis, eget pellentesque ante posuere. Nunc at turpis scelerisque, dictum nulla eget, dignissim mauris. Etiam faucibus, nisi non pharetra dignissim, libero tortor ornare turpis, eget commodo magna felis eget sapien. Nam et nunc a libero fermentum vulputate vel ac neque. Donec eget pulvinar ex. Vivamus eu pellentesque odio.

Nam efficitur fermentum purus, vel dignissim arcu pulvinar ut. Nam fermentum, dolor sit amet lobortis tempor, purus tellus facilisis nisl, eu elementum sem lorem iaculis nulla. Morbi ullamcorper, est sed convallis placerat, tellus nisl posuere mi, ac tincidunt erat nisi sed purus. Donec aliquam convallis ex a convallis. Quisque ac interdum eros, ut viverra justo. In lobortis leo ut laoreet mattis. Sed eleifend leo et dui sodales aliquet. Mauris vestibulum, sapien non aliquet pharetra, eros ligula imperdiet sem, et fringilla magna sem a justo. Aenean et enim rhoncus mi luctus bibendum. Aenean mollis quam felis, vitae faucibus quam vestibulum at. Integer in metus eu purus mattis condimentum commodo id sem. Aenean commodo felis vitae sapien commodo aliquam.

```
import pygame


GRAVITY = .2

pygame.init()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, img: pygame.Surface):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0
        self.img = img
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
    
    def gameOver(self):
        self.kill()
        pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/lose.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)

    def test(self):
        print(self)
  
    def jump(self):
        self.dy = -7

        if self.y <= 0 or self.y >= 600:
            self.gameOver()

        return True

    def update(self):
        self.y += self.dy
        self.dy += GRAVITY

display = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
back = pygame.image.load("./images/Background.png")
player = Player(10, 100, pygame.image.load("./images/Player.png"))
running = True

imgs = [
    pygame.image.load("images/1.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("images/2.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("images/3.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("images/4.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("images/5.png"),
    pygame.image.load("images/6.png"),
    pygame.image.load("images/7.png"),
    pygame.image.load("images/8.png"),
    pygame.image.load("images/9.png"),
]
i = 0

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.jump()

    if i >= len(imgs):
        i = 0

    player.img = imgs[i]
    player.update()

    screen.blit(back, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(player.img, (player.x, player.y))

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)  # limits FPS to 60

    i += 1

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) remove the Sprite from all [`pygame.sprite.Group`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). So where is your Group?